# Date object undefined

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script

```
function calcHoras(time1, time2, time3, time4)      
{

var time1;
var time2; 
var time3;
var time4;
Logger.log(time1);
var time = time2- time1;
Logger.log(time); 
  return converteTime(time) 

}

function converteTime(time) {
    var minutos = parseInt((time/(1000*60))%60)
      , horas = parseInt((time/(1000*60*60))%24);


    return horas + ":" + minutos;
}
```

-- // --

I need the values of the variables time1, time2, time3 and time4 to do the conditional structures (if, while, for), but in the script it only returns:

> [18-11-27 12: 01: 58: 601 PST] undefined
>   [18-11-27 12: 01: 58: 601 PST] NaN

time1, time2, time3, and time3 are objects of type date;

For cell of the worksheet the correct value is returned in hours and minutes;

Example of a condition that I need to do:

```
if (time1! = 0 && time2! = 0) {
        var time = time2 - time1;
} else {
        var time = time4 - time1;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs because you calcHoras is asiging undefined values to time1, time2, time3 and time4. To avoid this remove the following code lines

```
var time1;
var time2; 
var time3;
var time4;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruben

I removed the indicated lines, but the log (contents of the variable) keeps returning the same:

```
[18-11-28 07: 18: 44: 44 BRST] undefined
[18-11-28 07: 18: 44: 101 BRST] NaN
```

When instantiate test as object date, the value returned in the log is also:

```
var test = new Date (time1).getHours();
Logger.log (test);

[18-11-28 07: 41: 54: 629 BRST] NaN
```

Comment: It's a custom function. You need to use it inside a cell.